# Definition of degree of finite morphism plus context

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism of schemes, defined here,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_morphism

I always assumed that the *degree* of $f$ was the degree of the induced field extension
$$
[K(Y):K(X)],
$$
of course only defined if $f$ is dominant (hence surjective).

However, is this standard?

Or is the degree of $f$ defined as: Let $f$ locally be given by maps of rings $B_i \rightarrow A_i$. The degree of $f$ is the minimal number of elements of $A_i$ that generate it as a $B_i$ module?

I'm almost sure this does not work.

Q1: Why not? (excuse my lack of commutative algebra knowledge) (i am more than happy with just a sketchy answer to this!)

Q2: Does it work if we assume $X$ and $Y$ to be varieties over $\mathbb{C}$? If so/not, why?

Q3: What is indeed the commonly agreed definition of the degree of a finite map?

That's quite a lot, thanks for your answer!

Comment: When you say "locally", do you mean "there exists an affine covering such that ...." or "for any affine covering ...." ? Do you take the minimum of the "local degrees" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just want to note that you don't need any finiteness condition on $f$ to define the degree.  Any dominant morphism $f : X \to Y$ of integral schemes $X$ and $Y$ maps the generic point $x$ of $X$ to the generic point $y$ of $Y$, hence there is a canonical homomorphism $\mathscr{O}_{Y,y} \to \mathscr{O}_{X,x}$, which gives a field extension $R(Y) \hookrightarrow R(X)$.  (Thanks for Georges Elencwajg for simplifying my original argument.)

So we don't need finiteness conditions on $f$, or on $X$ and $Y$, to talk about the field extension $R(Y) \hookrightarrow R(X)$ or its degree $\deg(f) =  [R(X) : R(Y)]$.  However if one wants to ensure this degree is *finite*, it suffices to assume $f$ is locally of finite type and

(i) $f$ is closed, the dimensions of $X$ and $Y$ are equal (see [(Stacks, 02JX)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JX) and [(Stacks, 02NX)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02NX)),

or

(ii) $f$ is separated or quasi-compact (e.g. proper or even just universally closed), and there exists an affine open $V \subset Y$ such that the restriction $f^{-1}(V) \to V$ is finite [(Stacks, 02NX)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02NX).

Comment: Adeel, so if i understand correctly the notion of degree of a map and finiteness of a map are two independent ones? Which just happen to be very useful together as in Georges' answer?

Comment: Yes, finiteness is just an easy way to ensure that the degree is finite, but it is not necessary.

Comment: About Q1 and Q2, so the degree is never ever defined using the rank of the module as in my question?

Comment: It is possible that it coincides with that definition in some special case, but I am not sure.

Comment: I assume that that means it is indeed far from commonly done and i should not bother. Thanks again!

Comment: It's more probably a consequence of me working in far too much generality without understanding more concrete things first :)

Comment: Dear Adeel, your corollary is false: **all**  homomorphisms of fields are injective but many morphisms of integral schemes are **not** dominant.

Comment: Ah nice, i already wondered about that!

Comment: Ah sorry, I miscopied this from my notes.  Good catch!  And you mean nontrivial homomorphisms of course.

Comment: Dear Adeel, I am sorry to come back to that corollary, but your modified version makes no sense since in general **there is no morphism $R(Y)\to R(X)$**, as shown by the  example $\mathbb A^1\to \mathbb A^2$ in my answer. So there is no general notion of degree for non finite morphism.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I don't understand.  As you said, your morphism $\mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ is not dominant.  Dominant morphisms map generic points to generic points and there is always a canonical homomorphism $\mathscr{O}_{Y,y} \to \mathscr{O}_{X,x}$.

Comment: Dear Adeel, sorry, you are right. The corollary is true  but doesn't say very much since all morphisms of fields are injective anyway. (I really mean *all* morphisms of fields: the zero map is not a field morphism because it doesn't  send $1$ to $1$). And also, let me tell you that I really hate criticizing another answer when I wrote one myself: be assured that I only did so because there was a factual little problem.

Comment: Good point.  We don't need this corollary then, we just use the dominance of $f$ to get the field extension, and anyway we still get a well-defined degree for dominant morphisms (just in an easier way).  Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg and Adeel. Thanks for the discussion, reading such conversations is precisely why i love this site. Another question came up though. In the last comment to the accepted answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72364/finite-tale-morphism-of-varieties/72366#72366 Anton Geraschenko does use the fact that if the degree of the map is $n$, the map is locally given by an inclusion of rings $R \rightarrow S$ which makes $S$ into a free (!) module of rank $n$. The map here is assumed to be finite surjective étale. So this is "some special case", as you called them earlier Adeel?

Comment: Oh wait, also the varieties are assumed to be nonsingular, and over an algebraically closed field..

Comment: @Joachim, I'm not sure, I don't have much experience with finite morphisms.  Perhaps Georges knows.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to talk of function fields, it is prudent to consider only finite dominant morphisms $f\colon X\to Y$ between (locally noetherian) *integral* schemes.
The degree of $f$ is then defined as the degree of the corresponding extension of function fields $n=[k(X):k(Y)]$.
Qing Liu in [his wonderful book](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~qliu/Book/)  asks you to prove (Chapter5, Exercise 1.25) that **if $f$ is flat**, then all fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ of $f$ have $n$ points, if you count them suitably: $\dim_{k(y)}\mathcal O(f^{-1}(y))=n$ .

**Warning: The result is always false if $f$ is not flat!**
This is part of the exercise mentioned above.
For example if you normalize the node $N=V(y^2-x^2-x^3)\subset \mathbb A^2_k$, you obtain the finite morphism $$f\colon \mathbb A^1_k\to N\colon t\mapsto (t^2-1,t^3-t)$$ of degree $$[k(\mathbb A^1_k):k(N)]=[k(t):k(t^2-1,t^3-t)]=[k(t):k(t)]=1$$
However for the fiber over $P=(0,0)\in N$ you have $\dim_{k(P)}\mathcal O(f^{-1}(P))=2$ because $f^{-1}(P)$ consists of the two simple points $t=-1, t=+1$.

Comment: Georges, i understand that the degree is not defined for a finite morphism of varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ that is not dominant? (excuse the naive general use of schemes by the way, as you can probably tell i am too used to working with schemes with nice properties)

Comment: Yes, if a morphism is finite but not dominant, it is better not to assign a degree  to it . For example the morphism $f:\mathbb A^1\to \mathbb A^2: t\mapsto (t,0)$ is finite, but is not dominant and does not induce a morphism of fields $k(T_1,T_2) \to k(T_1)$. So  $f$  has no degree.

Comment: Georges, thanks a lot for the context and reference to the book. Since the other answer was more specifically about the notion of degree, i decided to accept that one, but your answer was definitely useful too!

Comment: That's quite all right  Joachim:  you are the only one capable of telling which answer best solves your problem. And, anyway, it gave me great pleasure  to answer your interesting question!

Answer (score 3):

Besides Adeel's nice answer, one can find another definition of the degree in case the morphism is flat and finite (and the schemes are locally Noetherian) in the Stacks project [02K9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02K9). This is actually the thing I hoped it would be, as I stated in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the nice edit!